# $f(z)={z\over 3z+1}$ maps

Tags: complex-analysis

Define

$H^{+}=\{z:y>0\}$

$H^{-}=\{z:y<0\}$

$L^{+}=\{z:x>0\}$

$L^{-}=\{z:x<0\}$

$f(z)={z\over 3z+1}$  maps

$1.$ $H^+\to H^+$ and $H^-\to H^-$

$2$. $H^+\to H^-$ and $H^-\to H^+$

$3.$ $H^+\to L^-$ and $H^-\to L^+$

$4.$ $H^+\to L^+$ and $H^-\to L^-$

If I take $z\in H^{+}$ then ${1\over z}\in H^{-}\Rightarrow {1\over z}+3={3z+1\over z}\in H^{-}$,also real line goes to real line, Now what can I conclude?please help.

Comment: If a complex number $z\in H^+$, then $z^{-1}\in H^-$, and conversely, if $z\in H^-$, then $z^{-1}\in H^+$ ($z\ne0$). So, since $(3z+1)/z\in H^-$, you have...

Comment: soooooooo $1$ is trueeeeeeee

Comment: Possible duplicate of [a function that maps half planes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157724/a-function-that-maps-half-planes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the map (defined for $z\ne0$)
$$
z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{|z|^2}\bar{z}
$$
sends positive imaginary part to negative and conversely, while $z\mapsto z+3$ doesn't change the imaginary part, if you start from $z\in H^{+}$, you have, in sequence
\begin{align}
&z\in H^{+}\\
&\frac{1}{z}\in H^{-}\\
&\frac{1}{z}+3=\frac{3z+1}{z}\in H^{-}\\
&\biggl(\frac{3z+1}{z}\biggr)^{-1}=\frac{z}{3z+1}\in H^{+}
\end{align}
Similarly if you start from $z\in H^{-}$.

Therefore (1) is true. This of course implies that (2) is false, because $H^{+}\cap H^{-}=\emptyset$.

In order to exclude (3) and (4) you need to find a counterexample.

But, if $z=-1/3+i\in H^{+}$, $z/(3z+1)=1-i/3\notin L^{-}$, which excludes (3). Similarly to exclude (4).

Comment: In options 3 and 4, you have used that $1 \in H^+$ and $-\frac{1}{4} \in H^4$ both have imaginary part zero. This is not correct right?

Comment: @Wanttolearn Oh, yes, what a mistake! I'll fix it ASAP.